# The examples on all the markdown help pages are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, editing-help

I've tried a few SE sites and it seems like all markdown help pages have broken examples. You can see it on the [meta se markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) or any other SE site. Here is a screenshot from SO:

[image: Super User Markdown help page]

It should looked like this:
http://web.archive.org/web/20140906093037/https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

As far as I can tell it's not a CSS problem. I think just some newlines are missing.

Comment: Indeed confirmed broken on IE11, FF and Chrome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and it will be out in the next release: 2745 on meta and 2014 on the network.

Comment: You didn't put enough [newlines in the syntax highlighting samples](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278280/syntax-highlighting-help-documentation).